# jZebra with Zebra TLP2844

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arabic, zebra-printers

How to use jZebra to print using TLP 2844 from client-side using javascript. I tried to print arabic text but I couldn't, I've tried to put the encode to UTF-8 but I still getting weird symbols. Is the problem from the font? If so please help me to change the font.

By the way I am using ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a similar question](http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/issues/detail?id=105&can=1&q=arabic) for ESC/P that was entered into the jZebra bug tracker.

On [page 113](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/EPL2_Prog.pdf#Page=113) of the programming manual, the CodePage support is listed.  I don't see Arabic listed specifically there, so you may need to render the text to a graphic, or choose a character set that is close enough to Arabic to be recognizable.

This is just speaking on behalf of research I've done over the internet, nothing hands-on.

-Tres

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But How can I do the mapping or rendering the text to a graphic. Also, If it would help to say that the text is is a couple of words only(static text).

Comment: Also, is it possilbe to change the font type?

Comment: This may not be ideal, but Zebra offers a tool "Zebra Setup Utilities" that can download resources to their printers.

https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7889

On their website, this software is listed as a download for your device.  Furthermore, Zebra offers excellent technical assistance for programming against their devices.  I cannot locate the technical specs of the TLP 2844, however it's successor GC420 supports ZPLII which also supports font and graphic downloading programatically.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer, I haven't used the pdf side of it though.

https://github.com/qzindustries/qz-print